# How to set my GUI window to full screen with my JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I have a full program in Java with GUI window and I would like to set this window when I press the maximize button to full screen to show my JTextArea bigger. 
I used in my GUI

```
public final class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private JLabel label1;
private JLabel label2;
private JLabel label3;
private JLabel label4;
private JLabel label5;

private JTextField field1;
private JTextField field2;
private JTextField field3;

private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;
private JButton button4;

private JScrollPane scrollpane;

private JTextArea visualization;
private JComboBox list;



public Program_GUI()
{

    this.initialize_graphic_components();  
}


public void initialize_graphic_components()
{
  this.setTitle("Test Program");
  this.setSize(600,400);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,400));
  this.setLayout(null);

  this.label2=new JLabel("Username:");
  this.label2.setBounds(20,50,120,20);
  this.add(label2);

  this.field2=new JTextField("");
  this.field2.setBounds(20,70,120,20);
  this.add(field2);

  this.visualization = new JTextArea(420,250);
  this.visualization.setEditable(false);
  this.scrollpane=new JScrollPane(this.visualization);
  this.scrollpane.setBounds(160, 50, 420, 250);
  this.add(scrollpane);


  ............here is the rest program.........

}
```

This is the begin of my program and I want my window to stretch to the monitor size when I press maximize button to be uniformity.
Thanks.

Comment: update your code what you have tried ?

Comment: It all depends on what layout managers you're using, something you haven't told us about. For instance if the JScrollPane that holds the JTextArea is held by a BorderLayout using container in the BorderLayout.CENTER position, then it will expand in all directions when the container expands.

Comment: where is textarea here ? post entire code

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line:

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

You want your layouts to be flexible an responsive to change in size and you can't expect this to work if you use no layout at all.  Again as per my comment that I posted almost an hour ago:

> It all depends on what layout managers you're using, something you haven't told us about. For instance if the JScrollPane that holds the JTextArea is held by a BorderLayout using container in the BorderLayout.CENTER position, then it will expand in all directions when the container expands.

Read the [layout manager tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and use them. End of story.

Answer (score 1):

All the container component has a Layout associated with it. Layout is the method to place the component on the container.

By default `JFrame` has `BorderLayout`. `BorderLayout` by default divide the container visible area in 5 section. Out of these five section `BorderLayout.CENTER` has the tendency to push other section to minimum width/height and occupy the space when no component is added to these sections.

Thus, For your requirement you should put the component in `BorderLayout.CENTER` section.

Answer (score 0):

Something you need like this

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text") ;
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
 JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10,10);
 box.add(area);
 frame.add(box);
```